# What utilities do I need to mount a virtual filesystem?

Tags: mount, initramfs, virtual-file-system

I am making an initramfs, and I want as few utilities as possible. Specifically, I don't want busybox. Since my root is zfs, I need `zfs.mount`. However, I also need to mount `proc`, `sysfs`, `devtmpfs`, and `devpts` for the initramfs, before I `switch_root`. I don't expect `zfs.mount` can handle these, so what do I need?

Comment: you want busybox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely don’t want Busybox, you’ll need `mount` (and `libmount`) from [`util-linux`](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/).